# const member function mutable

Tags: c++, constants, function-qualifier

As i am given to understand, the const specifier at the end of a member function means that the class's members cannot be modified, within that function, unless they are declared as mutable.
Having said that i have the following:

mns::list::list is a linked list implementation of mine which functions are not const.

```
template<typename T> class HashTable{
private:
      std::vector<mns::list::list<T> * > * hashtable;
      long long int size;

public:
        HashTable(int _size){
             hashtable = new std::vector<mns::list::list<T> * >(_size, NULL);
             size = _size;
       }
        ....

       bool insert(T _value) const {
             long long int hash_value = getHash(_value);

             if (hashtable->at(hash_value) == NULL) hashtable->at(hash_value) = new mns::list::list<T>(_value);
             else if (hashtable->at(hash_value)->find_forward(_value) == -1) hashtable->at(hash_value)->push_top(_value);
       }

       ....
}
```

and i have a function in my main:

```
void testhash(){
       HashTable<int> testhashtable1(100);
       std::cout << testhashtable1.find(45) << std::endl;
       testhashtable1.insert(45);
       std::cout << testhashtable1.find(45) << std::endl;
}
```

Given that HashTable::insert is a const function i assumed that i wouldn't be able to modify private member hashtable. But testhash() prints:

0

1

which means the member was modified... right?
So i seem to miss something here... Why was the private member vector hashtable modified?

Comment: `long long int` is very old way to write `intmax_t` or `ssize_t`. But if you want a size maybe it's better to have a unsigned integer ? like that `uintmax_t` or `size_t`. And you can have size of a vector with [size method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/)

Comment: @Stargateur `ssize_t` is not part of the standard. `size_t` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data member is a pointer to a vector. In the `const` member function `insert` all data members will be `const`, so your data member is now considered a const pointer to a vector. Since you do not try to modify the pointer itself (e.g. `hashtable = nullptr`) but the vector pointed to by it, the vector will be modified.

Answer (score 1):

- a const pointer to some type
- a pointer to some const type

they are totally different

Answer (score 0):

The `const` specifier for member functions allows that function to be called if the object is `const`. Therefore the function is not allowed to modify members or call non-const member functions.